# Can the instance which is created by Hilt be released automatically in Android Studio app?

Tags: android-studio, dagger-hilt

I use Hilt as Dependency Injection in my Android Studio project, the system will create the  MediaRecorder instance  automatically  using Code A,
and the class HandleMeter can use the `MediaRecorder` instance  automatically.

Can Hilt  release the `MediaRecorder` instance  automatically  when I close the APP ?

**Code A**

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ObjectModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMediaRecorder(): MediaRecorder {
        return  MediaRecorder()
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class HandleMeter @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val appContext: Context,
    private val mRecorder: MediaRecorder
): IHandleMeter {

    private fun startRecord(actionMax: () -> Unit){
        with(mRecorder) {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            ...
            prepare()
            start()
        }
    }

    private fun stopRecord(){
        try {            
            mRecorder.stop()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [MediaRecorder#release()](https://whenever%20an%20Activity%20of%20an%20application%20is%20paused%20(its%20onPause()%20method%20is%20called),%20or%20stopped%20(its%20onStop()%20method%20is%20called)) documentation you supposed to release `MediaRecorder` whenever the activity's `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods called. If you will do that, when your app will be closed, MediaRecorder will already be released.

But if you just close the app, then your process will be killed and `MediaRecorder` will be killed as well.

In order to release instance, you can declare clear() method in handleMeter:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class YourActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var handleMeter: HandleMeter

    override fun onResume() {
        handleMeter.resume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        handleMeter.clear()
    }
}

class HandleMeter @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val appContext: Context,
    private val mRecorder: MediaRecorder
): IHandleMeter {

    fun clear() {
        mRecorder.release()
    }

    fun resume() {
        // TODO: start record
    }
```

And call this method from `Activity.onPause()`. But in this case do not forget to resume recording in `Activity.onResume()` method.

Comment: Thanks! If I create `MediaRecorder` by myseflt, I can get a  reference of `MediaRecorder` instance, so I can release it on activity's `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods, but I can't get a reference of `MediaRecorder` instance when Hilt create the  `MediaRecorder` instance, so how can I release the  `MediaRecorder` instance created by Hilt? or can Hilt release 
the instance automatically?

Comment: It doesn't matter how MediaRecorder instance was created: by Hilt or by you. In order to release it you just need to manually call release() method. Please review my updated answer. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks! but `HandleMeter` is created by Hitlt automatically, so I can't also get the reference of `HandleMeter` instance, how can I invoke `fun clear()` on activity's `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods ?

Comment: You may inject `HandleMeter` to your Activity for example. Check my updated answer.